# What does "symbolically traceable" mean for a function?

Tags: python, pytorch, assert

Specifically, I am referring to Python and PyTorch, but I guess the term has a meaning more general than Python/PyTorch.

The PyTorch [docs](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch._assert.html) state for the function `torch._assert`:

> A wrapper around Python’s assert which is symbolically traceable.

1. What does that mean?
2. Why would I want to use this version of assert and not Python's builtin `assert`?

Comment: It's possible you have already seen this, but on the GitHub page for PyTorch, symbolic tracing "captures an intermediate representation (IR), which is represented as a doubly-linked list of Nodes"

Answer (score 0):

PyTorch is shipped with [FX](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/fx.html) toolkit that includes "three main components: *a symbolic tracer*, an intermediate representation, and Python code generation.".

A symbolic tracer builds a graph of the execution of some module (e.g., a function), i.e., the semantics of it. Such graph can be helpful to inspect the internals of your modules. As for using [`torch._assert`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch._assert.html), consider the situation where a tensor has undergone several manipulations causing it to violate some assertion.